# Amazon VPC DHCP renewal lease

Tags: dhcp, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm doing some self studying on networking and am using Amazon. I've been reading about DHCP and its lease time but have yet to find any resources illustrate how to change the default DHCP renewal lease time for VPC's or Subnets. I want to change the default DHCP renewal lease from it's default time to renew after 24 hours (I know this is not best practice but I'm simply doing this exercise for self studying purposes). I have read Amazons [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) explaining how to add DHCP option sets but it does not really help me with my needs. Hope my question is clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After further reading and studying it seems that you cannot change the DHCP of overlying resources such as VPC's or Subnets. The private & public ip that is associated with most AWS resources are static and will not change unless they are terminated or refreshed.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses